# Each element of an algebraic group has an nth root

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have a problem with this exercise form Shafarevich *Basic Algebraic Geometry*

> Let *G* be an algebraic group and suppose it to be abelian. Define
>   $\varphi_n:G\rightarrow G$ by $\varphi_n(g)=g^n$. Supposing that the
>   ground field has characteristic 0, prove that d$_e\varphi_n$ is a
>   nondegenerate linear map. Deduce from this that in a Abelian algebraic
>   group the number of elements of order *n* is finite, and that every
>   element has an *n*th root.

I cannot realize how to determine d$_e\varphi_n$, is it just $ng^{n-1}$?

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

The map $\phi_n$ is the composition
$$G \stackrel{\Delta}{\longrightarrow} G^n \stackrel{m}{\longrightarrow} G,$$
where $\Delta$ is the diagonal map and $m$ is the multiplication map.  So
$$d_e \phi_n = d_e m \circ d_e \Delta.$$
Now, $T_e G^n = (T_e G)^n$, and it is easy to see that $d_e \Delta$ is the diagonal inclusion and $d_e m$ is the sum map.  So $d_e \phi_n$ is simply multiplication by $n$.